How to validate Unicode letters in .NET that contain invisible chars
In .NET, I have a simple line that asserts a string must consist of letters or digits only
if (str.Any(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
{
  throw new Exception();
}

The problem is the string can be in any language and certain Unicode letters are represented by multiple characters. For example, in Turkish "i̇ş" contains "i" and combining dot above to represent the first letter.
As a result, the above validation fails. I don't want to hard-code invisible unicode chars to skip over. I'd like a generic solution that applies to all languages.
What is the fix for this?

Would this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textelementenumerator?view=net-8.0?

Just gave it a test and it seems to be working. I can see the accented letters in the loop without the hidden characters. Feel free to post it as an answer.

You can skip the NonSpacingMark category returned from char.GetUnicodeCategory(c). No need to hardcode anything.

The TextElementEnumerator class, knows about characters that belong together to represent a single "print character".
For example:
void Main()
{
    string sample = "Crème brûlée";
    
    Print(sample);
    sample = sample.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
    Print(sample);
    sample = sample.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    Print(sample);
    
    sample = "i̇ş";
    Print(sample);
}

IEnumerable<string> GetTextElements(string text)
{
    System.Globalization.TextElementEnumerator myTEE = System.Globalization.StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(text);
    myTEE.Reset();
    while (myTEE.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return myTEE.GetTextElement();
    }
}

void Print(string sample)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sample);
    foreach (var s in GetTextElements(sample))
    {
        foreach (var c in s)
        {
            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            {
                Console.Write($"({c})");
            }
            Console.Write("\\x");
            Console.Write(((int)c).ToString("X4"));
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.Write(" | ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

will print:
Crème brûlée
(C)\x0043  | (r)\x0072  | (e)\x0065 \x0300  | (m)\x006D  | (e)\x0065  | \x0020  | (b)\x0062  | (r)\x0072  | (û)\x00FB  | (l)\x006C  | (é)\x00E9  | (e)\x0065  | 
Crème brûlée
(C)\x0043  | (r)\x0072  | (è)\x00E8  | (m)\x006D  | (e)\x0065  | \x0020  | (b)\x0062  | (r)\x0072  | (û)\x00FB  | (l)\x006C  | (é)\x00E9  | (e)\x0065  | 
Crème brûlée
(C)\x0043  | (r)\x0072  | (e)\x0065 \x0300  | (m)\x006D  | (e)\x0065  | \x0020  | (b)\x0062  | (r)\x0072  | (u)\x0075 \x0302  | (l)\x006C  | (e)\x0065 \x0301  | (e)\x0065  | 
i̇ş
(i)\x0069 \x0307  | (ş)\x015F  | 

